# Modificar estado de um determinado componente pela resolução da tela usando ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, react-hooks

Estou realizando um trabalho onde dependendo do tamanho da resolução da tela, mostre um texto ou outro. Gostaria de saber que é possível utilizar, **no contexto de ReactJS**, um useState ou algo semelhante para que, quando a resolução da tela for alterada, o texto de um certo componente mude. Abaixo, tem minha tentativa de realizar essa operação, mas gostaria que fosse verificado toda vez que a resolução for alterada (um exemplo, quando virar a tela de um smartphone ou tablet)

```
export default function Teste() {
  const [texto, setTexto] = useState(
    window.innerWidth <= 768
      ? "Exibe esse aqui, no mobile/tablet"
      : "Exibe esse cara aqui em resoluções maiores"
  );

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={12}
        sx={{
          paddingTop: ["22px", "54px", "95px"],
          paddingLeft: ["38px", "93px", "254px"],
          height: ["16px", "21px"],
          fontSize: ["14px", "18px"],
          fontWeight: 700,
        }}
      >
        {texto}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tal como escreveste, podes utilizar um operador ternário e fazer:

```
const [texto, setTexto] = useState(
window.innerWidth <= 768
  ? this.setTexto('Exibe esse aqui, no mobile/tablet')
  : this.setTexto('Exibe esse cara aqui em resoluções maiores'));
```